# Integration of office apps as an iframe in my web application

Tags: office365, onedrive

I have a web application where I want my users to edit data in Microsoft Word Online. These should be real-time editing of files stored in Microsoft OneDrive or OneDrive for Business. I want to implement this withing an `<iframe>` in my web application.

I am not finding any such integration mechanisms but have seen similar integrations at https://www.box.com.

Answer (score 0):

The integration you're looking for uses the [WOPI protocal](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (think modern rev of WebDav). You'll also need to join of [Cloud Storage Provider Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cloud-storage-partner-program) (aka CSPP) in order for you WOPI implimentation to be whitelisted. The CSPP page outlines how the process works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped.

Answer (score -1):

Its not a ready made solution but this should put you in the correct direction. [Link1](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph), [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)

Comment: I have already gone through these links and APIs but none of them answers my query.